# Send HTML table with data via mail in php

Tags: php, html

I have a php code in my website to send a mail for contact Us section.
I want to show user's input in tabular format in **mail body**.

> php code

```
<?php
try{
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $comments = $_POST['comments'];
        $to = "abc@gmail.com";
        $response = mail($to, 'Query from website',
        "<table>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Contact Number</th> 
          <th>Email-Id</th>
          <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>'.$name'</td>
          <td>'.$phone'</td>
          <td>'.$email'</td>
          <td>.'$comments'</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      ");
      print_r($response); 
    } catch(Exception $e){
        print_r($e);
    }
?>
```

The issue is whole html code appears in mail body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have altered your code a bit. Your variable names didn't get the
>   values as they were inside qoutation marks(') and also they weren't
>   preceded and succeeded by (.). You didn't use content-type header to
>   use these HTML tags to get rendered properly. Please refer the below
>   code. Also, there must be an implode function to return these headers as they 
>   are stored in array.

```
<?php
try{
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $comments = $_POST['comments'];
        $to = "doke.prathamesh1994@gmail.com";
        $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '<table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Contact Number</th> 
          <th>Email-Id</th>
          <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>'.$name.'</td>
          <td>'.$phone.'</td>
          <td>'.$email.'</td>
          <td>'.$comments.'</td>
        </tr>
      </table>';
        $response = mail($to, 'Query from website', $message,implode("\r\n",$headers));
      print_r($response); 
    } catch(Exception $e){
        print_r($e);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer below example as described in the PHP manual page.

```
<?php
// Multiple recipients
$to = 'johny@example.com, sally@example.com'; // note the comma

// Subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// Message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johny</td><td>10th</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com';

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to tell `mail` what the content-type of your message is, by providing it with headers. The `mail` function's signature is:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Create a content-type header and pass it to `mail`:

```
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```